# R character factor to numeric vector

Tags: r, csv, types

I read in a csv file with "3:29" in one of the fields (without the quotation marks). This comes up as a factor. How can I convert this to a numeric vector e.g. c(3:29)? I tried as.vector() but this gives a string vector "3,4,5,6...29" (with the quotation marks, still character class).

EDIT Answer needs to be applicable to more general form, for example, the column could contain 3:6,7,9:11, which needs to be converted to the equivalent c(3:6,7,9:11).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
> eval(parse(text='3:29'))
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
[26] 28 29
```

Comment: If you want to extend this to handle strings like: `"3:6,7,9:11"` (as in the edited form of the question) you could turn it into a function `str2c <- function(s) eval(parse(text=paste("c(", s, ")")))`.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on `:` and convert to a vector of numerics and generate the call to `seq()` by hand:

```
> vars <- as.numeric(strsplit("3:29", ":")[[1]])
> seq(from = vars[1], to = vars[2], by = 1)
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
[26] 28 29
```

or slightly more elegantly by getting R to build the call to `` `:()` `` directly:

```
> do.call(`:`, as.list(as.numeric(strsplit("3:29", ":")[[1]])))
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
[26] 28 29
```

[**Updated** in light of **Edit** to original Q]

In the spirit of:

```
> require(fortunes)
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

this is as close as I can get without using `parse()`:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(strsplit(txt, ",")[[1]], ":"),
       function(x) {
           x <- as.numeric(x)
           if(length(x) == 2) {
               seq(x[1], x[2], by = 1) ## `:`(x[1], x[2])
           } else { 
               x[1]
           }
       }))
```

yielding:

```
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 11
```

...but it makes me thing this might be one of those times when using `parse()` might make sense ;-)

Comment: Takes care of the specific problem, but not the more general issue, for example, that column could also contain 3:6,7,9:11, which needs to be converted to the equivalent of c(3:6,7,9:11).

Comment: apologies for not being psychic ;-)

Comment: @Benjamin in that case, `parse()` is probably the simplest way to go, following @Michael Dunn's comment to @Prasad's answer. My general aversion to `parse()` has the resulted in the monstrosity lain before you in my updated Answer. Good Q by the way (+1 for that).